# CSS3-triangle before div

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I'm trying to add a triangle before a div using css, but it ends up under it.

http://jsfiddle.net/lasseedsvik/LwE7u/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    1234   

    <div id="toolbar">
        Want silly triangle before this div to left
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
     width: 500px;
}

#toolbar:before
{
    width: 44px;
    content: '';
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 44px 44px;
    border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;
}

#toolbar {
    float: right;
    width: 350px;
    height: 44px;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Is there something missing like display: inline or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS Positioning to set the triangle correctly, in the example below, I am using `position: relative;` on the parent element, and than use `position: absolute;` for the `:before` pseudo..and than use `left` property which is dobule of the elements `width`

Always you should wrap the `absolute` positioned elements with a `relative` positioned containers, else your element will fly out in the wild.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/LwE7u/5/)

```
#container {
     width: 500px;
}

#toolbar:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: -88px; /* Double the element size */
    width: 44px;
    content: '';
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 44px 44px;
    border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;
}

#toolbar {
    float: right;
    width: 350px;
    height: 44px;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
```

---

> Note: Generally when you are creating triangles using CSS, it's a
>   common practice to set the elements `height` and `width` to `0` so if
>   you want, just tweak them up.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your div#toolbar in `position:relative` and positionning your pseudo-element in an absolute manner. Then adjust position and margins to position it correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/LwE7u/2/